# Pass parameters to the Index() in Controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am building an ASP>NET MVC Core application using the EF. There are two method in my `Inventories` controller Index() and OrderItem() . When the OrderItem() method is called it performs some action and once the action is complete, I am trying to navigate back to the Index page. The Index() needs an input ID as an input parameter otherwise it returns the NOTFOUND().

Index() is like below

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id, string sortOrder, string searchString,
                                           int? pageNumber, string currentFilter)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
       ......................
   }
```

Another method with in the same controller where I am trying to return to the Index is like below

```
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Inventories", new { customerID });
```

When ye action is completed and the code tries to return the Index page the URL is like `https://localhost:44330/Inventories?customerID=460` and I get Not Found error

[image]

How to make the redirect to works so the URL looks like `https://localhost:44330/Inventories/Index/460`

Comment: Can you post here your Global.asax and subsidiary file content, please? What is name of your controller?

Comment: The name of the controller is `Inventories`. I dont have Global.asax file

Comment: Try to search method like: public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) with sequence like: routes.MapRoute. Do you have some? What is method content?

Comment: I dont see `RegisterRoutes` method. This is my first Web App in .NET mvc core using the EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try alter this:
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Inventories", new { customerID });

to this (if you are redirecting on action inside the same controller):

return RedirectToAction("Index", new { customerID = customerID });

or:
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { "customerID" = customerID });

left key must be the same as your route param name but it cant interfere with your variable name